# Migrate github repository to new computer?

Tags: github

This is a basic question. (I'm not a strong GitHub user, so sorry for this.)

- On my old computer I have a local repository that is pushed to GitHub regularly.
- On my new computer I want to have the same setting. But I already copied the files I need, and if I pull from GitHub to the new computer I think all new changes would be lost.

**Question**: *how to initialise my git repository locally on my new computer?*

Comment: Why not just git clone the repository on your new computer?

Comment: Simply `git clone <your repo address>` and you will have a complete clone of your repo on any machine. If this is a private repo, you will need to authenticate with your GitHub credentials

Comment: Thanks! @trivvz, wouldn't this erase my local changes on the new machine? And would I be able to push back to github any new changes?

Comment: @Jack, git clone never erases any changes, it just creates a new folder with the copy of your repo in it. Yes, you can commit to it and push from it, but you need to authenticate in order to do it (GitHub checks if you have write access)